# Can you catch an exception by the type of a conversion operator?

Tags: c++, exception, conversion-operator

I don't know how to phrase the question very well in a short subject line, so let me try a longer explanation.  Suppose I have these exception classes:

```
class ExceptionTypeA : public std::runtime_error
{
    // stuff
};

class ExceptionTypeB : public std::runtime_error
{
    // stuff

    operator ExceptionTypeA() const; // conversion operator to ExceptionTypeA
};
```

Can I then do this, and have it trigger the catch block?

```
try
{
    throw ExceptionTypeB();
}
catch (ExceptionTypeA& a)
{
    // will this be triggered?
}
```

I'm going to guess that it will not, which is unfortunate, but I thought I'd ask, since I couldn't find any info on it on the net or on SO.  And yes, I realize I could just run the program in my compiler and see what happens, but that wouldn't tell me what the standard says about this behavior, just what my compiler implements (and I don't trust it).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot. Standardese at `15.3/3`:

> A handler is a match for an exception object of type E if
>
> - The handler is of type `cv T` or `cv T&` and E and T are the same type (ignoring the top-level cv-
>     qualifiers), or
> - the handler is of type `cv T` or `cv T&` and T is an unambiguous public base class of E, or
> - the handler is of type `cv1 T* cv2` and E is a pointer type that can be converted to the type of the handler
>     by either or both of
>
>   - a standard pointer conversion (4.10) not involving conversions to pointers to private or protected or
>       ambiguous classes
>   - a qualification conversion

Your desired scenario matches none of these. `cv` means "const and/or volatile combination"

Comment: does this cover pointer to members ? for instance, pointer to member data are contravariant, so `int (Base::*)` can be converted to `int (Derived::*)`. can I catch the latter if I throw the former ? gcc seems to disagree, but the standard wording is a bit unclear.