# Is it possible to write an exception type that "catches" multiple different exceptions?

Tags: c++, exception, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I was wondering whether it would be possible (through clever conversion rules) to write an "exception" class that would help with the following:

Instead of writing:

```
try {
 ...
} catch (std::execption const e) {    // StdLib exceptions
} catch (CException* pEx) {           // MFC exceptions
} catch (CORBA::Exception const& e) { // CORBA exceptions
} // note handling code inside catch blocks omitted for brevity
```

It would be nice if a type could be constructed that would work like so:

```
try {
  ...
} catch( magic_exception_handle const& e) { // catches all three types mentioned above
  const std::string msg = e.what(); // could also provide generalized message extraction
}
```

Would this be possible? How?

Note: Other solutions I don't like:

- I can do `catch(...)` but I do *not* want to catch-all.
- catch-handler function:

  ```
  void handler3() {
    try {
      throw;
    } catch (std::execption const e) {    // StdLib exceptions
    } catch (CException* pEx) {           // MFC exceptions
    } catch (CORBA::Exception const& e) { // CORBA exceptions
    } // note handling code inside catch blocks omitted for brevity
  }

  ...
  try { ... } catch(...) { handler3(); }
  ```

  doesn't cut it either, because while any other exception would be thrown outwards, it first would catch *any* other exception which results in a premature stack unwinding before it is rethrown. (Which is very inconvenient for any resulting crash-dumps on Windows.)
- I could write a Macro for the catch block. (*ugh*)

So, is it possible to create a `magic_exception_handle` type? Has it been done?

Comment: can you have those 3 exceptions derive from a common base class (like `std::exception` eg. since you're already catching that) ? If so, you can catch that base class.

Comment: Since [conversions are not considered when matching exception handlers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2343294/20984), I don't think this can be done.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: `CException*` is a pointer - even if I were insane enough to hack the MFC sources, I couldn't make it derive from anything.

Comment: @LucTouraille: Thanks. I guess that answers the question.

Comment: @MartinBa: a quick read of Standard 15.3.3 shows there's no non-hackish options.  Re `CException*` not deriving from anything... off in hack land you could potentially catch it by `const void*` and recognise it by an initial pointer to RTTI CException's information, but that doesn't help as the other two types aren't pointers allowing similar discrimination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only real option is to invert the logic:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
auto convert_exceptions(F &&f, Args... &&args)
-> decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
   try {
      return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
   } catch (std::exception const e) {    // StdLib exceptions
      std::throw_with_nested(magic_exception{...});
   } catch (CException* pEx) {           // MFC exceptions
      std::throw_with_nested(magic_exception{...});
   } catch (CORBA::Exception const& e) { // CORBA exceptions
      std::throw_with_nested(magic_exception{...});
   }
}
```

You can now write:

```
try {
   convert_exceptions([&]() {
      // ...
   });
} catch (const magic_exception &e) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: **Ha!** Wrapping the code in a lambda + object that does the catching *instead* of writing a try-catch block isn't such bad idea. No need for the magic exception in your answer. I'd rename your `convert_exception` to `catch_exception` and provide the necessary handler code in it and then I have a reusable try-catch-block. -- Well, I would, if I'd had a C++11 compiler. But I have to remember this. :-)