# Catching lambda exception

Tags: c++

How can I catch a lambda thrown as an exception? I tried the following:

```
#include <functional>
int main() {
    try {
        throw [](){};
    } catch (std::function<void()> & fn) {
        fn();
    }
}
```

However the output is

> terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'main::{lambda()#1}'

Is it possible to catch thrown lambda exception?

Comment: Remember that each lambda is its own unique type, and it doesn't have any common base-type. Besides, throwing a lambda seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Furthermore, what is the *actual* problem you want to solve by throwing a lambda? You show us a wanted solution to an unknown problem, and ask us for help with that solution without telling us what it's supposed to solve. A typical [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I wouldn't actually code like that, I'm just interested in knowing whether it could be made to work in theory. I usually avoid exceptions in my real code whenever possible, so don't worry about that ;)

Comment: There's always `catch(...)`, if you don't care about the actual value, but need to catch it. You could even do tricks with `std::exception_ptr` later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can throw an `std::function` explicitly:

```
int main() {
    try {
        throw std::function<void()>([](){std::cout << "Hello there!";});
    } catch (std::function<void()> & fn) {
        fn();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int main() {
    try {
        throw [](){};
    } catch (std::function<void()> & fn) {
        fn();
    }
}
```

Two reasons why that exception handler will not be executed:

1. You are catching your exception by `lvalue` reference to an object of `std::function<void()>`, but the thrown object isn't of that type neither is it a base class of the thrown object.
2. Even if you changed the parameter to value, `std::function<void()>` will not be constructed from the lambda in exception handling. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2343294/1621391)

---

However, there are ways to make it "work". See answers [by SingerOfTheFall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42338735/1621391) and [by skypjack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42338754/1621391)

Answer (score 1):

The lambda has its own type that is not `std::function`. Therefore you are not catching the lambda, you are catching something else that is never thrown and can be assigned to a `std::function`.

To work around it, you can wrap the lambda directly in a `std::function` or a handler class an throw it.
As a minimal, working example (using a wrapper, that is a bit funnier to write):

```
#include <functional>
#include<utility>
#include<type_traits>
#include<iostream>

struct Base {
    virtual void operator()() = 0;
};

template<typename F>
struct Lambda: F, Base {
    Lambda(F &&f): F{std::forward<F>(f)} {}
    void operator()() override { F::operator()(); }
};

template<typename F>
auto create(F &&f) {
    return Lambda<std::decay_t<F>>{std::forward<F>(f)};
}

int main() {
    try {
        throw create([](){ std::cout << "doh" << std::endl; });
    } catch (Base &fn) {
        fn();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main requirement when catching an exception is to have a specific type for the object you're catching. Lambda's [don't have a specific, clean type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951377/what-is-the-type-of-lambda-when-deduced-with-auto-in-c11) that you can use. A clean way to do this is to wrap your Lambda with an `std::function`, and then you exactly know what you're catching.