# Is it possible to catch an exception of lambda type?

Tags: c++, exception, lambda

While it is good practice to throw only exceptions of types derived from `std::exception` class, C++ makes it possible to throw anything. All below examples are valid C++:

```
throw "foo";  // throws an instance of const char*
throw 5;      // throws an instance of int

struct {} anon;
throw anon;   // throws an instance of not-named structure

throw []{};   // throws a lambda!
```

The last example is interesting, as it potentially allows passing some code to execute at catch site without having to define a separate class or function.

But is it at all possible to catch a lambda (or a closure)? `catch ([]{} e)` does not work.

**Update (2022/11/14):**

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74437386/10662240) my own answer taking into account features of C++20.

Comment: I think we can assume `catch(...){}` is not desired.

Comment: `catch (...) { asm("call %rax"); }` unsafe problems call for unsafe solutions

Comment: @Joshua `catch(...)` is not desired if only for not giving access to the exception object being caught.

Comment: It turns out someone was already curious about lambda exceptions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42338470/catching-lambda-exception

Comment: @sudo rm -rf slash: I don't think you tried it. You got the x64 calling convention wrong.

Comment: @Joshua yes I didn't try it.  it was more of a joke than a serious idea.  I don't think there's anything forcing the compiler to use rax either.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Exception handlers are matched based on type, and the implicit conversions done to match an exception object to a handler are more limited than in other contexts.

Each lambda expression introduces a closure type that is unique to the surrounding scope. So your naive attempt cannot work, for `[]{}` has an *entirely different type* in the throw expression and the handler!

But you are correct. C++ allows you to throw any object. So if you explicitly convert the lambda before-hand to a type that matches an exception handler, it will allow you to call that arbitrary callable. For instance:

```
try {
    throw std::function<void()>{ []{} }; // Note the explicit conversion
} catch(std::function<void()> const& f) {
    f();
}
```

This may have interesting utility, but I'd caution against throwing things not derived from `std::exception`. A better option would probably be to create a type that derives from `std::exception` and can hold a callable.

Comment: Sure, I **would not** use this in production code. Rather, I was exploring intricacies of the language.
And while I did try to catch by pointer-to-function, it did not occur to me to throw and catch as `std::function`.

Comment: @KrzysiekKarbowiak - If the type is designed carefully I don't see why you can't do it in production. It may have interesting utility, like I noted. Ingenuity is after all taking what is known already and using it in a novel way :)

Comment: The exact rules used to match `catch` expressions are available in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343208/can-you-catch-an-exception-by-the-type-of-a-conversion-operator). Sadly, it looks like there's no way to catch the lambda if it's thrown as `throw []{};`, as there's no public base class and the type is not a pointer so the pointer rules don't apply.

Answer (score 25):

C++ allows you to throw anything. And It allows you to catch whatever you throw. You can, of course, throw a lambda. The only problem is that, to catch something, you need to know the type or at least a parent type of that something. Since lambdas do not derive from a common base, you have to know the type of your lambda to catch a lambda. The main issue with that is that every lambda expression will give you an rvalue of a [distinct type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.prim.lambda#closure-1). That means that both your throw and your catch need to be based on the same lambda expression (note: the same expression, not just some expression that looks exactly the same). One way I can think of to make this work to some degree would be to encapsulate the creation of the lambda to throw in a function. That way, you can call the function in your `throw` expression, and use the return type of the function to deduce the type to `catch`:

```
#include <utility>

auto makeMyLambda(int some_arg)
{
    return [some_arg](int another_arg){ return some_arg + another_arg; };
}

void f()
{
    throw makeMyLambda(42);
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        f();
    }
    catch (const decltype(makeMyLambda(std::declval<int>()))& l)
    {
        return l(23);
    }
}
```

Try it out [here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0Aauto+makeMyLambda(int+some_arg)%0A%7B%0A++++return+%5Bsome_arg%5D(int+another_arg)%7B+return+some_arg+%2B+another_arg%3B+%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+f()%0A%7B%0A++++throw+makeMyLambda(42)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++try%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++f()%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++catch+(const+decltype(makeMyLambda(std::declval%3Cint%3E()))%26+l)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++return+l(23)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:62.5,l:'4',m:65.46681664791902,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:34.53318335208099,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:62.5,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:37.5,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).

You could also just use `std::function` like suggested in some of the other answers, which is potentially a more practical approach. The downsides of that, however, would be

- It means you don't actually throw a lambda. You throw an `std::function`, which is not really what you asked for
- The creation of an `std::function` object from a lambda [can throw an exception](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap.func.con#11)

Answer (score 8):

You can throw and catch a `std::function`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void f() {
        throw std::function<void(void)>([]{std::cout << "lambda\n"; });
}

int main()
{
        try{ f(); }
        catch( std::function<void(void)> &e)
        {
                e();
                std::cout << "catch\n";
        }
}
```

Output:

```
lambda
catch
```

Answer (score 2):

A lambda is a unique anonymous type.  The only way to name a lambda instance's type is to store it in a variable, then do a `decltype` on that variable type.

There are a few ways you can catch a thrown lambda.

```
try  {
  throw []{};
} catch(...) {
}
```

in this case you cannot use it, other than throwing it again.

```
try  {
  throw +[]{};
} catch(void(*f)()) {
}
```

a stateless lambda can be converted to a function pointer.

```
try  {
  throw std::function<void()>([]{});
} catch(std::function<void()> f) {
}
```

you can convert it to a `std::function`.  The downside with `std::function` is that it heap allocates for larger lambdas, which could in theory cause it to throw.

We can eliminate that heap allocation:

```
template<class Sig>
struct callable;

template<class R, class...Args>
struct callable<R(Args...)> {
  void* state = nullptr;
  R(*action)(void*, Args&&...) = nullptr;
  R operator()(Args...args) const {
    return action( state, std::forward<Args>(args)... );
  }
};

template<class Sig, class F>
struct lambda_wrapper;
template<class R, class...Args, class F>
struct lambda_wrapper<R(Args...), F>
:
  F,
  callable<R(Args...)>
{
  lambda_wrapper( F fin ):
    F(std::move(fin)),
    callable<R(Args...)>{
      static_cast<F*>(this),
      [](void* self, Args&&...args)->R {
        return static_cast<R>( (*static_cast<F*>(self))( std::forward<Args>(args)... ) );
      }
    }
  {}
  lambda_wrapper(lambda_wrapper && o):
    F(static_cast<F&&>(o)),
    callable<R(Args...)>( o )
  {
    this->state = static_cast<F*>(this);
  }
  lambda_wrapper& operator=(lambda_wrapper && o)
  {
    static_cast<F&>(*this) = (static_cast<F&&>(o));
    static_cast<callable<R(Args...)>&>(*this) = static_cast<callable<R(Args...)>&>( o );
    this->state = static_cast<F*>(this);
  }
};

template<class Sig, class F>
lambda_wrapper<Sig, F> wrap_lambda( F fin ) {
  return std::move(fin);
}
```

now you can do:

```
try {
  throw wrap_lambda<void()>([]{});
} catch( callable<void()> const& f ) {
}
```

`callable` is "lighter weight" type erasure than `std::function` as it cannot cause new heap memory to be allocated.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2ffa2e8355dd3de).

Comment: @krzy you are missing the `+`; I never said implicitly.  `throw +[]{};`

Answer (score 0):

It is now 2022, the current C++ standard is C++20, and it gives us some more interesting opportunities, which I realised after seeing this talk: [C++ Lambda Idioms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBAduq0RGes), especially [this part](https://youtu.be/xBAduq0RGes?t=2854).

Lambdas are now default-constructible and allowed in unevaluated contexts (e.g. decltype), which allows us to do this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using lambda = decltype([]{ std::cout << "I am a lambda\n"; });

auto foo()
{
    throw lambda();
}

int main()
{
    try {
        foo();
    } catch (const lambda& l) {
        l();
    }
}
```

[Try it out on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/scdo57oEc).

So it looks like currently the short answer is **Yes, it is possible to catch an exception of lambda type**.